# Hook function call linux mint

Tags: c++, linux, hook, code-injection, mprotect

some days ago I wrote a simple hook/detour by patching a single call instruction.
It worked on Ubuntu 12.xyz (32bit), now I updated to Linux Mint 17.1(32bit) and I get Segmentation fault.

I have two projects

- target project which calls a function named goodGuy
- library project loaded by dlopen() which overwrites the offset from the call instruction in target application

Before overwriting the call instruction offset, I modify the protection of the page by:

```
mprotect(pageOf(address),pagesize,PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC|PROT_READ)
```

this works fine (returns 0).

When I debug my programm, it crashs while trying to write to the address of the call:

```
memcpy((void*)(address + 1),(void*)&callOffset,4);
```

Looks like I am not allowed to overwrite instructions, but why ?

I diabled ALSR and used `-z execstack -fno-stack-protector` flags with g++.

Do you know how to allow my application to write instructions ?

Thank you, Alex

**EDIT**

Sorry guys, here is the code:

target application:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

void goodGuy();
//full lib path !
char libPath[] = "INSER_YOUR_PATH_HERE/lib.so";

int main(){
  dlopen(libPath,RTLD_NOW);
  goodGuy();
  return 0;
}

void goodGuy(){
    printf("good guy :)\n");
}
```

and the shared lib code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void badGuy();

int pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);

void *pageOf(void* p){
    return (void*)((unsigned int)p & ~(pagesize - 1));
}

extern "C" void __attribute__ ((constructor)) DllLoad(void){
    uint32_t addressOfCall = 0x0804862a; //Address where goodGuy is called in target app
    uint32_t addressOfNextInstruction = addressOfCall + 5;
    uint32_t callOffset = (uint32_t)badGuy - addressOfNextInstruction;

    mprotect(pageOf((void*)(addressOfCall + 1)),pagesize, PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC|PROT_READ);
    memcpy((void*)(addressOfCall + 1),(void*)&callOffset,4);
}

void badGuy(){
  printf("bad guy :(\n");
}
```

To find out the addressOfCall open the target application with gdb `gdb target` and display the main function by `disas main` and have a look at `+29`

```
gdb$ disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main()
   0x0804860d <+0>: push   ebp
   0x0804860e <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x08048610 <+3>: and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x08048613 <+6>: sub    esp,0x10
   0x08048616 <+9>: mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],0x2
   0x0804861e <+17>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x804a060
   0x08048625 <+24>:    call   0x80484f0 <dlopen@plt>
    ___________
   |0x0804862a| <+29>:  call   0x8048636 <goodGuy()>
   |__________|
   0x0804862f <+34>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x08048634 <+39>:    leave  
   0x08048635 <+40>:    ret
```

Comment: Is that really a segfault, or something else? Also, maybe SELinux is interfering, and stopping you from effictively setting that mask using mprotect.

Comment: I get `Speicherzugriffsfehler` in english it means seg fault, gdb says the same. I get this exception by `mov [esp] , edx` where esp is the address of the call-offset and edx is the new offset. I dont knot SELinux, but I will have a look, danks.

Comment: This will fail if `address` happens to be very close to the end of a page. Long shot, but try printing it out in hex. (Also, a complete self-contained example would help others reproduce your issue.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller: He says `mprotect` returned 0... If it returned "success" but actually failed, that would be a kernel bug, SELinux or no.

Comment: @al-eax: though my German is quite ok, I'd have a hint for you: `export LANG=C` will make errors appear in the original (English) wording.

Comment: @Nemo & MarcusMüller thanks for your reply and for the hints. I updated my post with source code, some includes may not be necessary.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't always get loaded to the same address? I think there's some protection mechanism that does that, which may be activated in your Linux. Maybe using `uint32_t(&main)+29` would work better?

Comment: @celtschk thanks for ur reply. the address of the call instruction never changes. the exceptions is thrown by memcpy to this address. So there is no random address protection.